# transformer identification

Tags: transformer, identification, repair

i need to identify this transformer to find its datasheet. Found inside a no-turning-on SONY AIR-SA10, and when measuring the two secondary coils, with 110Vac applied on the primary, is 0Vca in both. Its strange because the secondary coils are not open circuit, although they meausure 2ohms and 0,7ohms, i'm not shure if i can consider this as short circuit on the windings or a normal really low output impedance.

Anyways, normal or not, i need to find a replacement, and i dont know the secondary coil requirements of the circuit.

I emailed SONY for the schematic and got no response.

[image]
[image]
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the original problem. The readings i posted didn't make sense, except they did. It was the old "internally hidden fuse" trick... added an external fuse between the primary poles and everything works as its supposed to.

Comment: That may have been a thermal fuse; if so, you need to know why it overheated and tripped, or you are operating it without that protection.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This speakers where given to me like this, don't know how it burned, but my best guess would be as this is a 110Vca transformer, and i live in a country with a 220Vca power grid, probably the previous owner just plugged it straigh to the wall and the first protecction that blew up was the transformer internal fuse, as all the other fuses where intact. In situations like this i'm not shure if i can trace the fault even further...